# How to access variables of a sub-function in a class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I am facing problems with calling a variable outside of a subfunction:

```
class ABC():
    def ___init___(self):
        function_A()
        function_B()
    def function_A(self):
        self.A = 5
        def subfunction_of_A(self):
            self.B = 2
            self.function_B()
        subfunction_of_A()
    def function_B(self):
        C = self.B

 Start = ABC()
```

I always geht the error:
`'ABC' object has no attribute 'B'` for `C = self.B`

How can I make self.B accessible from outside?

Thanks a lot :)

------- EDIT/UPDATE ----------
Okay, I think i might need to update my question a little bit:

```
class ABC():
    def ___init___(self):
        self.function_A()
        self.function_B()
    def function_A(self):
        self.A = 5
        def subfunction_of_A(self):
            self.B = 2
        subfunction_of_A(self)
        print(self.B) # This prints 2 and works as it should!
    def function_B(self):
        C = self.B # In this line I receive the error that ABC.B does not exist --> Why is that?

 Start = ABC()
```

Comment: I guess you are refering to instance attributes? As in, if you create a new `instance` of the `ABC` class, e.g. like so `abc = ABC()` you fail to access the attributes?

Comment: I am pretty new to Python, but I think the problem is that you don't declare an attribute A or B at the top level in the class, then have your functions and subfunctions (I have to admit, the idea of subfunction is weird to me too) modify these attributes.

Comment: @mapf: Yes that is sort of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit:*

```py
class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.function_A()
        self.function_B()
    def function_A(self):
        self.A = 5
        def subfunction_of_A(self):
            self.B = 2
        subfunction_of_A(self)
    def function_B(self):
        print(self.B) # This prints 2 and works as it should!
        C = self.B

Start = ABC()
```

this time your problem seems to be that your `___init___` has 3 underscores instead of 2... `__init__`

previous answer:

you're never calling your "sub function"

```
class ABC():
    def function_A(self):
        self.A = 5
        def subfunction_of_A(self):
            self.B = 2
        subfunction_of_A(self) # notice this line

    def function_B(self):
        self.C = self.B


abc = ABC()
abc.function_A()
abc.function_B()
print(abc.C) # prints 2
```

the only way for B to be set is for that function to run even if its nested...its a weird way to set up a class but there you go

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question. Actually I call the "sub function" in the function itself. And the functions are called from the init of the class. Do you have any clue?

Comment: you have to pass self to the "sub function" for it to affect the current object- notice how I call it `subfunction_of_A(self)`

Comment: I have edited my question again - I still do not understand why I can not access it?!

Comment: I edited my answer to your current code...if it's still not working you're obviously not posting your actual code and I can't tell you what's wrong with it